# Match text between two strings with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.x

I would like to use a regular expression that matches any text between two strings:

```
Part 1. Part 2. Part 3 then more text
```

In this example, I would like to search for "Part 1" and "Part 3" and then get everything in between which would be: ". Part 2. "

I'm using Python 2x.

Comment: I'm trying it with my own strings but somehow something is not working. It's always returning `None`. See: `ht = re.search(pattern=r'(fun n : nat => (.*?) : 0 + n = n)', string='(fun n : nat => eq_refl : 0 + n = n)')`

Comment: for my string `import re

ppt = '(fun n : nat => ?Goal : 0 + n = n)'
match = re.search(r'^(.*)\?\w+(.*)$', ppt)
re_ppt = f'{re.escape(match.group(1))}(.+){re.escape(match.group(2))}'
print(re_ppt)
print(re.match(re_ppt, "(fun n : nat => eq_refl : 0 + n = n)").groups())`

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use `re.search`

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Part 1. Part 2. Part 3 then more text'
>>> re.search(r'Part 1\.(.*?)Part 3', s).group(1)
' Part 2. '
>>> re.search(r'Part 1(.*?)Part 3', s).group(1)
'. Part 2. '
```

Or use `re.findall`, if there are more than one occurances.

Comment: Note that the wanted answer is `". Part 2. "`, so the regular expression should be r'Part 1(.*?)Part 3'. See my answer blow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this will not match the new line character.

Comment: do you mind explaining what the regular expression means? I'm trying it with my own strings but somehow something is not working. It's always returning `None`. See: `ht = re.search(pattern=r'(fun n : nat => (.*?) : 0 + n = n)', string='(fun n : nat => eq_refl : 0 + n = n)')`

Comment: for my string `import re

ppt = '(fun n : nat => ?Goal : 0 + n = n)'
match = re.search(r'^(.*)\?\w+(.*)$', ppt)
re_ppt = f'{re.escape(match.group(1))}(.+){re.escape(match.group(2))}'
print(re_ppt)
print(re.match(re_ppt, "(fun n : nat => eq_refl : 0 + n = n)").groups())`

Comment: what if I wanted all the strings with 3 digits between Part1 and Part3?

Comment: If you also need to match across multiple lines (i.e. if the expected match can include line break characters), you need to either compile the regex with `re.S`/`re.DOTALL` or just add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern, i.e. `r'(?s)Part 1\.(.*?)Part 3'`

Answer (score 43):

With regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Part 1. Part 2. Part 3 then more text'
>>> re.search(r'Part 1(.*?)Part 3', s).group(1)
'. Part 2. '
```

Without regular expression, this one works for your example:

```
>>> s = 'Part 1. Part 2. Part 3 then more text'
>>> a, b = s.find('Part 1'), s.find('Part 3')
>>> s[a+6:b]
'. Part 2. '
```

Comment: How did you come up with 6, as the user said anything in between ?

Comment: @VetrivelPS its 6 because the length of "part 1" is 6. str.find() returning the location for the first char.

Comment: do you mind explaining what the regular expression means? I'm trying it with my own strings but somehow something is not working. It's always returning `None`. See: `ht = re.search(pattern=r'(fun n : nat => (.*?) : 0 + n = n)', string='(fun n : nat => eq_refl : 0 + n = n)')`

Comment: for my string `import re

ppt = '(fun n : nat => ?Goal : 0 + n = n)'
match = re.search(r'^(.*)\?\w+(.*)$', ppt)
re_ppt = f'{re.escape(match.group(1))}(.+){re.escape(match.group(2))}'
print(re_ppt)
print(re.match(re_ppt, "(fun n : nat => eq_refl : 0 + n = n)").groups())`

Answer (score 0):

I feel these example with increasing complexity are interesting:

```
ppt = 'abc HERE abc'
ept = 'abc TERM abc'
re_ppt = ppt.replace('HERE', '(.+)')
print()
print(f'{re_ppt=}')
out = re.search(pattern=re_ppt, string=ept)
print(out)
print(out.groups())

ppt = 'abc HERE abc HERE abc'
ept = 'abc TERM1 abc TERM2 abc'
re_ppt = ppt.replace('HERE', '(.+)')
print()
print(f'{re_ppt=}')
out = re.search(pattern=re_ppt, string=ept)
print(out)
print(out.groups())

print()
ppt = """(fun n : nat =>
 nat_ind (fun n0 : nat => n0 + 0 = n0) ?Goal"""
print(f"{ppt=}")
ept = """(fun n : nat =>
 nat_ind (fun n0 : nat => n0 + 0 = n0) (eq_refl : 0 + 0 = 0)"""
print(f'{ept=}')
pattern_meta_var = r'\?(\w)+'
_ppt = re.sub(pattern=pattern_meta_var, repl='HERE', string=ppt)
print(f'{ppt=}')
_ppt = re.escape(_ppt)
print(f'{ppt=}')
re_ppt = _ppt.replace('HERE', '(.+)')
print(f'{re_ppt=}')
out = re.search(pattern=re_ppt, string=ept)
print(out)
print(out.groups())

print()

# sometimes the actual proof term missing won't have white spaces surrounding it but the ppt will have surrounding spaces where the hole
# would be. So in goal cames I removed the surrounding whitespaces. Then inserted a regex that accepts a hole with or
# without surrounding white spaces. That way in case the proof term in the hole does have surrounding white spaces then
# the regex hole catcher would match it anyway.
ppt = """\n   (fun (n' : nat) (IH : n' + 0 = n') => ?Goal0) n)"""
ept = """\n   (fun (n' : nat) (IH : n' + 0 = n') =>\n\teq_ind_r (fun n0 : nat => S n0 = S n') eq_refl IH : S n' + 0 = S n') n)"""
print(f"{ppt=}")
print(f'{ept=}')
pattern_meta_var = r'\s*\?(\w)+\s*'
_ppt = re.sub(pattern=pattern_meta_var, repl='HERE', string=ppt)
print(f'{_ppt=}')
_ppt = re.escape(_ppt)
print(f'{_ppt=}')
re_ppt = _ppt.replace('HERE', '\s*(.+)\s*')
print(f'{re_ppt=}')
out = re.search(pattern=re_ppt, string=ept)
print(out)
assert out is not None, f'expected two holes matched but go {out=}'
print(out.groups())

print()
ppt = """(fun n : nat =>
 nat_ind (fun n0 : nat => n0 + 0 = n0) ?Goal
   (fun (n' : nat) (IH : n' + 0 = n') => ?Goal0) n)"""
print(f"{ppt=}")
ept = """(fun n : nat =>
 nat_ind (fun n0 : nat => n0 + 0 = n0) (eq_refl : 0 + 0 = 0)
   (fun (n' : nat) (IH : n' + 0 = n') =>
    eq_ind_r (fun n0 : nat => S n0 = S n') eq_refl IH : S n' + 0 = S n') n)"""
print(f'{ept=}')
pattern_meta_var = r'\s*\?(\w)+\s*'
_ppt = re.sub(pattern=pattern_meta_var, repl='HERE', string=ppt)
print(f'{_ppt=}')
_ppt = re.escape(_ppt)
print(f'{_ppt=}')
re_ppt = _ppt.replace('HERE', '\s*(.+)\s*')
print(f'{re_ppt=}')
out = re.search(pattern=re_ppt, string=ept)
print(out)
print(out.groups())
```