# Python: replace Japanese word with brace, such as {keyword: 部屋}, {keyword: 公園}, ..... with 'keyword'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

there are some Japanese sentences like following:

```
 {keyword: 部屋}いいね!
 {keyword: 公園}は綺麗です.
 私は{keyword: 部屋捜査}です。
```

..........
     .........

I want to replace the substring like :{keyword: 部屋},{keyword: 公園}..... with 'keyword'.

For example:

```
input: 私は{keyword: 部屋捜査}です  

output: 私はkeywordです
```

My trying code is following and but it is wrong, the result is same:

```
import re
s = '{keyword: 賃貸}'    
t = re.sub(r"\{keyword:[あ-んア-ン一-]+\}", 'keyword', s)
print(t)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What about just matching any chars but `}` after `{keyword:`? Try [`re.sub(r"\{keyword:[^}]*}", 'kd', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/i19GqU/1)

Comment: can you paste a sample output also along with input string?

Comment: Hi thanks you guys, I have updated question

Comment: hi @Wiktor Stribiżew, could you explain your regex in detail, please!

Comment: If zippa's answer works for you, you do not need a regex.

Comment: Matching a string between two strings is a long solved issue, so I decided to close as a dupe. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32680048/3832970) shows how to use `.*?` to match from a starting delimiter to the closing one. You do not even need a negated character class if you consider it too complex.

Comment: hi @ Wiktor Stribiżew, what's zippa's answer? It seems that he deleted, could you add it, please!

Comment: what's meaning of '[^}]' ?

Answer (score -1):

Use the following:-

```
inputString = "私は{keyword: 部屋捜査}です"
t = re.sub(r"\{keyword:[^}]*}", 'keyword', inputString)
print(t)
```

Comment: Could you explain in detain, please! for example; what's meaning of '[^}]'?

Comment: Hi @tktktk0711, `[^}]` is used to define one character, that is not `}`. For further details, use reference:- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#more-metacharacters and