# python how to extract the text between two known words in a string?

Tags: python, regex

how to extract the text between two known words in a string with a condition that the text between these words can be i) 1 character ii) 1 word iii) 2 words etc.?

Sample Text:

```
text = ("MNOTES - GEO GEO MNOTES 20 231-0005 GEO GEO GEO GEO GEO MNOTES SOME REVISION MNOTES CASUAL C GEO GEO GEO GEO GEO MNOTES F232322500 MNOTES HELP PAGES GEO GEO GEO GEO MNOTES SHEET 1 OF 3 GEO GEO MNOTES CASUAL E. GEO GEO MNOTES SITPOPE/TIN AY GEO GEO MNOTES R GEO GEO GEO GEO MNOTES 22+0436/T.SKI/11-AUG-1986 GEO GEO GEO GEO MNOTES 231-0045 GEO")
```

I have a string like above that have multiple occurrences of these two known words `'MNOTES'` and `'GEO'`, however the text between them can be anything and any number of words.

I wanted to extract sometimes the text that has only one character between those two known words or sometimes the text that has 2 words between those two known words or sometimes the text that has 6 words between those two known words etc.,
So, how can i extract along with the condition  ?

Comment: You want to use regular expressions. Check out this answer, I hope it solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680030/match-text-between-two-strings-with-regular-expression

Comment: Would be good if you post your desired output from this string.

Comment: condition 1: extract text that has one character between MNOTES and GEO output 1: '-' , 'R' ;  condition 2: extract text that has two words between MNOTES and GEO output 2: '20 231-0005' , 'CASUAL C', 'CASUAL E.', 'SITPOPE/TIN AY'

Answer (score 4):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

```
import re

re.findall('MNOTES(.*?)GEO', text)
```

This results in:

```
[' - ', ' 20 231-0005 ', ' SOME REVISION MNOTES CASUAL C ', ' F232322500 MNOTES HELP PAGES ', ' SHEET 1 OF 3 ', ' CASUAL E. ', ' SITPOPE/TIN AY ', ' R ', ' 22+0436/T.SKI/11-AUG-1986 ', ' 231-0045 ']
```

**Edit**

To get a specific amount of characters the following will work:

```
re.findall('MNOTES\s?(.{1})\s?GEO', text)
```

Results in

```
['-', 'R']
```

and to get only results that are 6-8 characters long:

```
re.findall('MNOTES\s?(.{6,8})\s?GEO', text)
```

Results:

```
['- GEO ', 'CASUAL C', 'R GEO ', '231-0045']
```

Comment: Your output is wrong. As per your answer it would be "[' - ', ' 20 231-0005 ', ' CASUAL C ', ' SHEET 1 OF 3 ', ' CASUAL E. ', ' R ', ' 231-0045 ']"

Comment: i wanted to extract based on the count of words or characters. for example, like get me the output only when the text between the words are one character...in this case i wanted only '-', 'R' alone, how can i put that as condition in the script?  please suggest.

Comment: @PS1212 no, see: https://repl.it/repls/ProfuseCorruptDirectory what I have in my answer is correct

Comment: I cannot seem to get per words working but this get's you split by character count