# How to create a list containing all strings between 2 identical patterns

Tags: python-3.x

Given a string as an example below:
string = 'a bcde:Title - 1 xyz;dummy-a bcde:Title - 2.1 xyz;dummy-a bcde:Title - 3.1 xyz;dummy-'
My interesting content is between 'a bcde:' and ' xyz' , so in this case I would like to get these strings (**Title - 1**,**Title - 2.1**,**Title - 3.1**) out and create a list.

```
# following is the code
string = 'a bcde:Title - 1 xyz;dummy-a bcde:Title - 2.1 xyz;dummy-a bcde:Title - 3.1 xyz;dummy-'
start = 'a bcde:'
end = ' xyz'
n = [1,2,3]
title_list = []
for index in n:
    title = (string.split(start))[index].split(end)[0]
    title_list.append(title)
print(title_list)
```

With the current code, it works as expected, because the string is short enough, I could define occurrence (n = [1,2,3]). While the string is too big to count then I start to have a problem.I am looking for ways that are more efficient and explicitly.
I expect to create a string list containing any info between start & end patterns as shown below:
['Title - 1', 'Title - 2.1', 'Title - 3.1',....]

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at `regex`; see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680030/match-text-between-two-strings-with-regular-expression). you could do

```py
import re

string = 'a bcde:Title - 1 xyz;dummy-a bcde:Title - 2.1 xyz;dummy-a bcde:Title - 3.1 xyz;dummy-'

print(re.findall(r'a bcde:(.*?) xyz', string))
# ['Title - 1', 'Title - 2.1', 'Title - 3.1']
```

or a bit more versatile as a function:

```py
def match_between(s, p0, p1):
    expr = re.compile(p0 + r'(.*?)' + p1)
    return re.findall(expr, string)

patterns = (r'a bcde:', r' xyz')
print(match_between(string, *patterns))
# ['Title - 1', 'Title - 2.1', 'Title - 3.1']
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for :)

Comment: great! by the way, to construct and test regex patterns, I find this site pretty useful: https://regex101.com/